# Pandas: can not write to excel file

Tags: python, pandas

Trying this example from the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

```
writer = ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
writer.save()
```

I found out that I can not write to an excel file with the error

```
TypeError: copy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'font'
```

I'm using Panda 0.16 on a Mac pro.

EDIT: 
writing to an xls file worked just fine. I do not insist in having an xlsx file, just wonder why it does not work.

Comment: Please show the exact code that caused the error, and more of the error trace

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For fast solution replace this

```
xcell.style = xcell.style.copy(**style_kwargs)
```

with

```
pass
```

At pandas/io/excel.py line 778.

openpyxl upgraded their api and pandas also need to be updated for support openpyxl.

Comment: Oh no, you are not supposed to change library files. Better changer version

Comment: As i said. Fast but dirty.

Comment: Although hacking a library works, it is definitely evil.

Answer (score 11):

As per their [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html), pandas depends

> on openpyxl version 1.6.1 or higher, but lower than 2.0.0

The last [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) version lower than 2.0.0 being version 1.8.6, you should simply remove your current openpyxl version and run:

```
pip install openpyxl==1.8.6
```

if your using pip, or find an equivalent way to install this specific version.

Comment: I installed `openpyxl==1.8.6` . My Pandas version is `pandas===0.16.0-294-g45f69cd`. This does not help. The problem remains.  Now I really need the xlsx format because of the max lines limitation..

Answer (score 10):

If you don't care whether the headers have borders around them and bold font, and you don't want to restrict the version of openpyxl, the quickest way is to overwrite the `header_style` dictionary to be `None`.

If you also have dates or datetimes, you must also explicitly set the workbook's `date` and `datetime` formats to `None`:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
pd.core.format.header_style = None  # <--- Workaround for header formatting

dt = datetime.now()
d = datetime.date(datetime.now())
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'c1': 'alpha', 'c2': 1}, {'c1': 'beta', 'c2': 2}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'c1': dt, 'c2': d}, {'c1': dt, 'c2': d}])

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    writer.date_format = None # <--- Workaround for date formatting
    writer.datetime_format = None  # <--- this one for datetime
    df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
    df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
```

Not clear why the keyword arguments never make it through the openpyxl deprecation wrapper...but they don't.  In addition if you're formatting any other cells use the new [openpyxl api](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/).

All of these problems go away if you have Anaconda, by the way.

Comment: This worked for a simple example, but then I tried it on a df with dates in it and got `TypeError: copy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'number_format'`

Comment: Wow. The pandas writer explicitly overrides null arguments for the formatting to make them default, rather than taking a default value and letting the user override. wtf. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

An update to pandas should slove this.

```
pip install -U pandas
```

It works for pandas version 0.17+