# How to add an empty Worksheet into an existing Workbook using Pandas ExcelWriter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to add an empty excel sheet into an existing Excel File using python xlsxwriter.

Setting the formula up as follows works well.

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(file_name)
worksheet_cover = workbook.add_worksheet("Cover")
Output4 = workbook
Output4.close()
```

But once I try to add further sheets with dataframes into the Excel it overwrites the previous excel:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('Luther_April_Output4.xlsx') as writer:
    data_DifferingRates.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Differing Rates')
    data_DifferingMonthorYear.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Differing Month or Year')
    data_DoubleEntries.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Double Entries')
```

How should I write the code, so that I can add empty sheets and existing data frames into an existing excel file.

Alternatively it would be helpful to answer how to switch engines, once I have produced the Excel file...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not forced use `xlsxwriter` try using [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Simply pass 'openpyxl' as the Engine for the `pandas` built-in [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) class. I had asked a question a while back on [*why* this works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220247/pandas-excel-writer-using-openpyxl-with-existing-workbook). It is helpful code. It works well with the syntax of `pd.to_excel()` and it won't overwrite your already existing sheets.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

book = load_workbook(file_name)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
data_DifferingRates.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Differing Rates')
data_DifferingMonthorYear.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Differing Month or Year')
data_DoubleEntries.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Double Entries') 

writer.save()
```

Comment: Hi MattR
Thanks a lot for your advice. Since I could see that openpyxl also allows me to change cell formats, ad comments and ad formulas into the excel file. that would be what I need??!

But since I also want to have the engine read commands from "xlsx" as well as "xlsm" the code in this link seems to be best for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220247/pandas-excel-writer-using-openpyxl-with-existing-workbook

Comment: But could you please explain the code from line 4 onwards?! the "supported extensions" command seems to be right, but I don't get why and whether i need the rest as well...

class _OpenpyxlWriter(ExcelWriter):
    engine = 'openpyxl'
    supported_extensions = ('.xlsx', '.xlsm')

    def __init__(self, path, engine=None, **engine_kwargs):
        # Use the openpyxl module as the Excel writer.
        from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

        super(_OpenpyxlWriter, self).__init__(path, **engine_kwargs)

       
        self.book = Workbook()

Comment: @phi.lue - if this answer or the other answer has solved *this* question you posted, please up vote them or mark as answered. As for the question you left in the comments, that is a completely different question and would require you to post another question :)

Comment: @phi.lue the other annswer (to which you're referring) is simply highlighting the *source code* for the `pandas.ExcelWriter` class, which is a wrapper for other i/o Excel libraries. You do not implement that code directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pandas.ExcelWriter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) with optional `mode='a'` argument for appending to existing Excel workbook.

> You can also append to an existing Excel file:

```
>>> with ExcelWriter('path_to_file.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:`
...     df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3')`
```

**However unfortunately,** this requires using a different engine, since as you observe the `ExcelWriter` does not support the optional `mode='a'` (append). If you try to pass this parameter to the constructor, [it raises an error](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cb00deb94500205fcb27a33cc1d0df79a9727f8b/pandas/io/excel.py#L1663).

So you will need to use a different engine to do the append, like [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). You'll need to ensure that the package is installed, otherwise you'll get a "Module Not Found" error. I have tested using `openpyxl` as the engine, and it is able to append new a worksheet to existing workbook:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(engine='openpyxl', path='Luther_April_Output4.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:
    data_DifferingRates.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Differing Rates')
    data_DifferingMonthorYear.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Differing Month or Year')
    data_DoubleEntries.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Double Entries')
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the advice. I had tried this trick perviously. Stupidly enough the engine "xlsxwriter" wont let me use this functionality 'mode="a"'. Do you have any idea on how to change that engine while writing excel half way into the code?

I have used xlsxwriter so far since it has the most extensive literature and most commands such as also formatting cells etc...

Comment: @phi.lue Unfortunately it seems the ExcelWriter does not support append mode :( but see revision to my answer for using the `openpyxl` engine instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write the data into a new file.  This works for me:

```
#  Write multiple tabs (sheets) into to a new file
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

Work_PATH = r'C:\PythonTest'+'\\'
ar_source =  Work_PATH + 'Test.xlsx'
Output_Wkbk = Work_PATH + 'New_Wkbk.xlsx'

# Need workbook from openpyxl load_workbook to enumerage tabs
#   is there another way with only xlsxwriter?
workbook = load_workbook(filename=ar_source)
# Set sheet names in workbook as a series.  
# You can also set the series manually tabs = ['sheet1', 'sheet2']
tabs = workbook.sheetnames  
print ('\nWorkbook sheets: ',tabs,'\n')

# Replace this function with functions for what you need to do
def default_col_width (df, sheetname, writer):
    # Note, this seems to use xlsxwriter as the default engine.
    for column in df:
        # map col width to col name. Ugh.
        column_width = max(df[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
        # set special column widths 
        narrower_col = ['OS','URL'] #change to fit your workbook
        if column in narrower_col: column_width = 10
        if column_width >30: column_width = 30
        if column == 'IP Address': column_width = 15 #change for your workbook
        col_index = df.columns.get_loc(column)
        writer.sheets[sheetname].set_column(col_index,col_index,column_width)

    return  
    # Note nothing is returned.  Writer.sheets is global.

with pd.ExcelWriter(Output_Wkbk,engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    # Iterate throuth he series of sheetnames
    for tab in tabs:
        df1 = pd.read_excel(ar_source, tab).astype(str)
        # I need to trim my input
        df1.drop(list(df1)[23:],axis='columns', inplace=True, errors='ignore')

        try:
            # Set spreadsheet focus
            df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=tab, index = False, na_rep=' ')
            # Do something with the spreadsheet - Calling a function
            default_col_width(df1, tab, writer)  
        except:
            #  Function call failed so just copy tab with no changes
            df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=tab, index = False,na_rep=' ')
```

If I use the input file name as the output file name, it fails and erases the original.  No need to save or close if you use With... it closes autmatically.