# Python: TypeError: Value must be a sequence

Tags: python, typeerror, openpyxl

My code:

```
def write_excel(filename, sheetname, dataframe):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
        workBook = writer.book
        try:
            workBook.remove(workBook[sheetname])
        except:
            print("Worksheet does not exist")
        finally:
            dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname, index=False)
            writer.save()


write_excel(r"C:\Users\Harshad\Documents\Project\Files\Backtest.xlsx", '888', df_normalized)
```

Error at:

```
 write_excel(r"C:\Users\Harshad\Documents\Project\Files\Backtest.xlsx", '888', df_normalized)
```

I am getting at error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Harshad/Documents/Project/Code/Step-4-Normalizing 888Sport Odds.py", line 66, in <module>
    write_excel(r"C:\Users\Harshad\Documents\Project\Files\Backtest.xlsx", '888', df_normalized)
  File "C:/Users/Harshad/Documents/Project/Code/Step-4-Normalizing 888Sport Odds.py", line 55, in write_excel
    with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
  File "C:\Users\Harshad\PycharmProjects\Self Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 25, in __init__
    book = load_workbook(self.path)
  File "C:\Users\Harshad\PycharmProjects\Self Project\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\Harshad\PycharmProjects\Self Project\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 280, in read
    self.read_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\Harshad\PycharmProjects\Self Project\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 266, in read_worksheets
    pivot = TableDefinition.from_tree(tree)
  File "C:\Users\Harshad\PycharmProjects\Self Project\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 83, in from_tree
    obj = desc.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\Harshad\PycharmProjects\Self Project\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 85, in from_tree
    return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
  File "C:\Users\Harshad\PycharmProjects\Self Project\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 85, in <listcomp>
    return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
  File "C:\Users\Harshad\PycharmProjects\Self Project\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "C:\Users\Harshad\PycharmProjects\Self Project\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\pivot\table.py", line 601, in __init__
    self.x = x
  File "C:\Users\Harshad\PycharmProjects\Self Project\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 25, in __set__
    raise TypeError("Value must be a sequence")
TypeError: Value must be a sequence
```

This code worked till yesterday. How can I resolve it?
Thanks

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code fails to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with openpyxl. The version I was running was 3.0.5.
It works perfectly with 3.0.4 but not with the later versions. I did not get a chance to test the 3.0.6 version though.
Downgrading to 3.0.4 helped and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it will help, but the engine parameter is deprecated. This other answer looks promising though:

Solution: [Pandas Excel Writer using Openpyxl with existing workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220247/pandas-excel-writer-using-openpyxl-with-existing-workbook)

Docs:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html