# Where can I find the ExcelWriter documentation

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to work with the *ExcelWriter* class. Though the *ExcelWriter* can be called with *pd.ExcelWriter* like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744863/python-how-to-use-excelwriter-to-write-into-an-existing-worksheet) post, I can't find any information about it in the [Pandas API](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html). So where can I find a documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to read ["Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter" documentation](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) and [Pandas Cookbook IO (Excel)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#writing-excel-files).

Another useful option is to use interactive Python shells like `ipython` or `Jupyter Notebook` - just type function/method/constructor name followed by `?` (question mark) and press `Enter` - it'll show you a `docstring`.

Demo in `ipython`:

```
In [84]: pd.ExcelWriter?
Init signature: pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine=None, **kwargs)
Docstring:
Class for writing DataFrame objects into excel sheets, default is to use
xlwt for xls, openpyxl for xlsx.  See DataFrame.to_excel for typical usage.

Parameters
----------
path : string
    Path to xls or xlsx file.
engine : string (optional)
    Engine to use for writing. If None, defaults to
    ``io.excel.<extension>.writer``.  NOTE: can only be passed as a keyword
    argument.
date_format : string, default None
    Format string for dates written into Excel files (e.g. 'YYYY-MM-DD')
datetime_format : string, default None
    Format string for datetime objects written into Excel files
    (e.g. 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')

Notes
-----
For compatibility with CSV writers, ExcelWriter serializes lists
and dicts to strings before writing.
```