# Write to an existing xlsx file, overwriting just some sheets in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl, pandas.excelwriter

I have an excel file with several sheets, say, `Data 1`, `Data 2` and `Pivots`.

The sheets `Data 1` and `Data 2` have one table each. 
The sheet `Pivots` has only pivot tables whose data sources are the tables on `Data 1` and `Data 2`.

What I'd like to do is to rewrite the data sheets with data in two dataframes, say `df1` and `df2` respectively, while keeping the pivot tables linked to the same sheets. The idea is to run a script, replace `Data 1` and `Data 2` and refresh the pivot tables to get updated data.

`pd.ExcelWriter(xlsx_file)` won't work because it replaces the file.
The approach below was adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34746838) answer.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book=load_workbook(xlsx_file)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlsx_file, engine = "openpyxl")
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
writer.sheets.pop("Pivots", None)
data_sheets = ["Data 1", "Data 2"]

for (k, df) in enumerate([df1, df2]):
    df.to_excel(writer, data_sheets[k], index=False)
writer.save()
```

This failed because the sheet `Pivots` indeed kept the data in the cells, but the pivot table was gone, along with all its formatting. It was just hard values.

I also perused [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370977/how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas) question, but couldn't make it work.

How do I go about doing this simple task?

---

I uploaded an example file which can be download [here](https://ufile.io/kvqtz). For your convenience, here are two dataframes to replace the data sheets:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Category": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "A"], "Value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"SKU": ["AB", "BB", "CB", "DB", "AB"], "No of Items": [3, 2, 7, 4, 12]})
```

---

As asked by a user below, I'm leaving here my failed try at his solution proposal (the pivots and all their formatting are gone, just their hardvalues remain).

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

df1 = pd.DataFrame([["A", 1], ["B", 2], ["C", 3], ["D", 4], ["A", 5]], columns=["Category", "Value"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["AB", 3], ["BB", 2], ["CB", 7], ["DB", 4], ["AB", 12]], columns=["SKU", "No of Items"])

wb = load_workbook("xlsx_file.xlsx")
sheets = ["Data 1", "Data 2"]

for (idx, df) in enumerate([df1, df2]):
    ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheets[idx])
    rows = dataframe_to_rows(df)
    for (r_idx, row) in enumerate(rows):
        if r_idx != 0:
            for (c_idx, value) in enumerate(row[1:]):
                ws.cell(row=r_idx+1, column=c_idx+1, value=value)

wb.save("xlsx_file.xlsx")
```

Comment: can you upload a sample .XLSX file somewhere?

Comment: @MaxU Done. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: You can overwrite first two sheets, but i don't think you can preserve your pivots - they'll be converted to static data sets...

Answer (score 0):

The pandas side of things knows nothing about pivots so you should avoid using `to_excel()` and use the utilities that openpyxl provides for going from a dataframe to a worksheet and back.

You may need to change the definition of the pivot tables in which case you are largely on your own: openpyxl should preserve the structure but provides no additional functions for managing them. You will have to rely on the specification of pivot tables in ECMA 376 / ISO 29500

Comment: I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36664027/7454646) answer of yours, but it still broke the pivot table. Any idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: A link to the excel file is in the question. The code I used is there too. Thank you very much.