# Getting AttributeError 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet' - while writing data frame to excel sheet

Tags: excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have the following code, and I am trying to write a data frame into an "existing" worksheet of an Excel file (referred here as test.xlsx). Sheet3 is the targeted sheet where I want to place the data, and I don't want to replace the entire sheet with a new one.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
book = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets) # *I am not sure what is happening in this line*
df.to_excel(writer,"Sheet3",startcol=0, startrow=20)
```

When I am running the code line by line, I am getting this error for the last line:

AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet'. Now why am I seeing this error when I am not trying to add worksheet ?

Note: I am aware of this similar issue [Python How to use ExcelWriter to write into an existing worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744863/python-how-to-use-excelwriter-to-write-into-an-existing-worksheet) but its not working for me and I can't comment on that post either.

Comment: it is most likely due to the piece of code that you do not know what is happening. Why do you need that in there?

Comment: we need book and sheet attributes to add sheets or save to excel. 'writer.book = book' sets the result of load_book as the writer's book attribute so you can manipulate it. 'writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)' - this line generate the sheets attribute. I think it is needed so that we can edit the targeted sheet.

Comment: have you tried looping one sheet at a time? I've done that in the past with success

Comment: I have not. How do you propose to do that ? I am quite new to python - if you could elaborate little bit with code that'd be helpful

Comment: Pandas defaults to using xlsxwriter. You need explicitly to set the engine to openpyxl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `append_df_to_excel()` helper function, which is [defined in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075046/5741205):

Usage:

```
append_df_to_excel('test.xlsx', df, sheet_name="Sheet3", startcol=0, startrow=20)
```

Some details:

`**to_excel_kwargs` - used in order to pass additional **named** parameters to `df.to_excel()` like i did in the example above - parameter `startcol` is unknown to `append_df_to_excel()` so it will be treated as a part of `**to_excel_kwargs` parameter (dictionary).

`writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}` is used in order to copy existing sheets to `writer` openpyxl object. I can't explain why it's not done automatically when reading `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')` - you should ask authors of `openpyxl` module about that...

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, this works. Two big differences I am seeing here in your code: 1. df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)  will you plz explain little about this parameter **to_excel_kwargs - I was not using this ? 2. writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl') use of openpyxl as an engine . Also if you can explain this line too - that will be big help - writer.sheets = dict(
            (ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `openpyxl` as the engine when you are creating an instance of `pd.ExcelWriter`.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, -3],'B':[1,2,6]})
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('examples/ex1.xlsx') #Already existing workbook
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('examples/ex1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') #Using openpyxl

#Migrating the already existing worksheets to writer
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = {x.title: x for x in book.worksheets}

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet4')
writer.save()
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I tried this code. Instead of adding to 'Sheet3' it creates 'Sheet31' and puts the dataframe there - 'df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet3', startcol=0, startrow=20, index = 0)' . But I want it to write within Sheet3 not create a new one.

Comment: Doesn't work with latest pandas and openpyxl

Answer (score 0):

openpyxl has support for Pandas dataframes so you're best off using it directly. See http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

This did work for me (pandas version 1.3.5)

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2], 'b':[1,2,3],'c':[2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'aa':[10,11,12], 'bb':[11,12,13],'cc':[12,13,14]})

with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx') as writer:
    for i, df in enumerate([df1, df2]):
        df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=f'sheet_{i}', index=False)
```