# How do you export a two dimensional list into excel?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I will just keep it short and simple . I have a two dimensional list that i would like to import to excel spreedsheet or a csv ? Here is my 2d list below.

'df = [[3, 7, 9, 28],[3, 7, 17, 28],[7, 25, 27, 28],[7, 17, 21, 27, 28],[3, 4, 28],[4, 7, 28],[4, 7, 14, 28],[3, 14, 28],[3, 7, 14, 28],[7, 11, 28],[3, 11, 28],[3, 7, 12, 28],[7, 11, 12, 28],[3, 11, 12, 28],[3, 7, 11, 28]]'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python How to use ExcelWriter to write into an existing worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744863/python-how-to-use-excelwriter-to-write-into-an-existing-worksheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple approach that might work on your end :)

```py
df = [[3, 7, 9, 28],[3, 7, 17, 28],[7, 25, 27, 28],[7, 17, 21, 27, 28],[3, 4, 28],[4, 7, 28],[4, 7, 14, 28],[3, 14, 28],[3, 7, 14, 28],[7, 11, 28],[3, 11, 28],[3, 7, 12, 28],[7, 11, 12, 28],[3, 11, 12, 28],[3, 7, 11, 28]]


import csv

with open('myspreadsheet.csv', 'w', newline = '') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter = ',')
    for row in df:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: works but is there a way to get it to straight down without the brackets and comma