# Extract the data and modify an existing excel with openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, pandas-datareader

I would like to modify an existing excel via openpyxl.
The purpose is to take finance data and insert it in the specific columns so that it can perform the calculations.

I would like column 1 to show the opening prices

I write this code.

```html
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

from openpyxl import load_workbook

start = dt.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime(2019, 1, 1)

ticker = "AAPL"

yahoo = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)

#print(yahoo['Open'])


wb = load_workbook('aa.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "Change Sheet__"

ws["A"].value(aaa)

wb.save("aa.xlsx")
```

The error is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Davide\Desktop\aa.py", line 23, in 
    ws["A"].value(aaa)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: Does the code work? whats the error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Davide\Desktop\aa.py", line 23, in <module>
    ws["A"].value(aaa)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python How to use ExcelWriter to write into an existing worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744863/python-how-to-use-excelwriter-to-write-into-an-existing-worksheet)

Comment: Can you edit my code with the example ? I try but it isn't work

Comment: What do you think `ws['A']` is?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this should work :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('aa.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1'] # choose your sheet.
```

#### then we decide your column to replace with your df.

```
col_to_replace = 'A'
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cell = f'{col_to_replace}{index+2}'
    ws[cell] = row[0]

wb.save('aa.xlsx')
```

Comment: Or just use the methods provided by the library.

Comment: @Charlie Clark can you post an example? From my experience working with pandas it usually overwrites excel sheets destroying any dependent formulas, although it's been a while since I've done anything excel based.

Comment: I never mentioned Pandas. openpyxl worksheets have `iter_rows()` and `iter_cols()` methods which the OP would know if they'd read the documentation.